# Unable to boot either Ubuntu or Windows after kernel panic

Tags: 10.10, kernel, dual-boot, windows-7

Today I have been unable to boot into my Ubuntu (10.10) or Windows (7) partition.

Ubuntu kernel panics on boot with the error:

```
init: hash.c:296: Assertion failed in nih_hash_search: hash != NULL
```

I can boot into a LiveUSB environment, and from there can access all my files on my 3 partitions (1 ext4, 2 NTFS). I have also ran fsck on the ext4 partition and ntfsfix on the 2 NTFS partitions, both not finding any errors at all. And Grub is intact and have also tried a reinstall of it.

So at the moment I'm currently stuck using a LiveUSB, and would like to see if there are any other options other than reinstalling.

Thanks.

**Update**

I've now ran chkdsk using my Windows recovery disk, and it found errors and fixed them, but I am still unable to boot into either Windows or Ubuntu

**Update #2**

I've decided to just re-install Ubuntu and start again as I didn't really want to spend any more time looking around whilst I need this computer for work. Thanks for all your help though.

Comment: why can't you boot windows 7?
also, you should be able to reinstall the kernel from a chroot (I'm guessing) and bypass the panic - though I'll leave that for someone from the kernel team to confirm.

Comment: When booting into Windows I get an error saying to use my Windows disc (which I can't get access to at the moment as I am at work). And I have two options of either continuing and escaping. Both options just send me back to GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't boot into either, perhaps your bootloader is hosed. Try reinstalling that from your LiveUSB environment.

Comment: I've tried reinstalling GRUB following this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202 I got the successfully installed message, but I still got a kernel panic and windows would not boot.